# Why there is an error as "<identifier> expected" with the Derived constructor arguments?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, identifier

I have defined a constructor of super-class `Base`, but during the declaration of arguments of the constructor in the subclass `Derived`, why is it showing the error *"identifier expected"*?

```
  class Base 
        {     
             int x,y;       
             Base(int x1,int y1)
                {
                    x=x1;
                    y=y1;
                }
                void viewxy()
                {
                    System.out.println("x = "+x+" y= "+y);
                }
                void viewsum()
                {
                    System.out.println("x+y: "+(x+y));
                }
        }
        class Derived extends Base
        {
                int z;
                Derived(x1,y1,z1)
                {
                    super(x1,y1);
                    z=z1;
                }
                void viewz()
                {
                    System.out.println("z = "+z);
                }
                void viewderivedsum()
                {
                    System.out.println("x+y+z= "+(x+y+z));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions - you use camelCase for method names, like `viewDerivedSum()`

Comment: I appreciate the Easter accept 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Derived(x1,y1,z1)
```

You put the **types** in front of your parameters on the base class, what makes you think you can now omit them?

Surprisingly enough, the syntax rules are always the same, as you need something like:

```
Derived(int x1, int y1, int z1)
```

instead.